# How to make a constraint in a Recycler View in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

My activity_main.xml file has a Recycler View like most of them do, I think. Here, I would like to push my contact list down, so I could put a task bar at the top, but I can't operate with constraints here. When I try to push it in the Design tab by hand, it doesn't work either.

Can someone help me with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="100dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_contact" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(The `constraintTop_toTopOf` is probably useless or wrong, so tell me if it's right or wrong.)

Comment: Can you please attach your code as well

Comment: I attached it now.

Comment: You're using RelativeLayout, constraintTop_toTopOf is ConstraintLayout's layout param either use ConstraintLayout as parent or alignParentTop as layout param

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed the problem days ago, but I'll try that out to see if it's more efficient!